# Jhipster Gateway Zuul Route

Tags: jhipster, netflix-zuul, jhipster-registry

Hi I'm adding the zuul route as below to register in the jhipster gateway and it is successful.

> ```
> routes:
>     myhost:
>         path: /greeting/**
>         url: http://localhost:8080
> ```

However, it is appending the url as below after registration.

http://localhost:8282/greeting/greeting

I am expecting [http://localhost:8282/myhost/greeting/](http://localhost:8282/myhost/greeting)

What value should I pass under zuul route to get the above url. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the eureka client id of your service ?

Comment: There is no service instance. I will just add path and url. The aim is to register the normal rest service to the jhipster gateway without making any changes in the rest service. It works. But the url is what repeating the path twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assigned empty value to the path. Now the url is generated as expected